# How to set custom email format in jquery Validation

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation and I want to set a particular email format.

For example : qwerty@demo.com , In this I want set validation for "@demo.com".I I dont want any other format like gmail,yahoo etc after @.

How do I do that in Jquery Validation plugin ??

Answer (score 5):

You can use the pattern rule specified in the additional-methods file like

```
rules: {
    useremail: {
        email: true,
        pattern: /.+@demo\.com$/
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cqb8f1c2/)